# Llenar campos a partir de un Select con una base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Saludos, estoy haciendo un Autocomplete con *PHP*, *Ajax* y *JQuery* poblado por una base de datos en *SQL* que constantemente cambia de registros y con las opciones de ese Select tengo que llenar varios campos de texto de un formulario que pueden o no ser modificados por el usuario.
He buscado ejemplos con Autocomplete y no me muestra resultados. Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

**Interfaz del usuario**

```
$(function() {
        $("#plaza").autocomplete({
            source: "pruebaPlaza.php",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#plaza').val(ui.item.plaza);
                $('#clave_ct_necesidad').val(ui.item.clave_ct_necesidad);
                $('#clave_ct_nomina').val(ui.item.clave_ct_nomina);
                $('#clave_ct_analitico').val(ui.item.clave_ct_analitico);
                $('#qna_ini').val(ui.item.qna_ini);
                $('#qna_fin').val(ui.item.qna_fin);
                $('#asignatura').val(ui.item.asignatura);
                $('#observaciones').val(ui.item.observaciones);

             }
        });
    });
```

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  Plaza:  <input id="plaza">
  <br>
  Centro de Trabajo con Necesidad: <input type="text" id="clave_ct_necesidad'">
  <br>
  Centro de Trabajo Nómina: <input type="text"  id="clave_ct_nomina" >
  <br>
  Centro de Trabajo Analítico: <input type="text"  id="clave_ct_analitico" >
  <br>
  Quincena de inicio: <input type="text"  id="qna_ini" >
  <br>
  Quincena de término: <input type="text"  id="qna_fin">
  <br>
  Asignatura: <input id="asignatura">
  <br>
  Observaciones: <input id="observaciones">
```

**Script que autocompleta**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    include ('config.php');

$return_arr = array();
/* Si la conexión a la base de datos , ejecuta instrucción SQL. */
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.propuesta_vacancias where plaza like '%".$searchTerm."' ";
    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($dbcon, $sql);
    /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
    while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $plaza=$row['plaza'];
        $clave_ct_necesidad=$row['clave_ct_necesidad'];
        $clave_ct_nomina=$row['clave_ct_nomina'];
        $clave_ct_analitico=$row['clave_ct_analitico'];
        $qna_ini=$row['qna_ini'];
        $qna_fin=$row['qna_fin'];
        $asignatura=$row['asignatura'];
        $observaciones=$row['observaciones'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    } 


/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
?>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Edito: En esta versión estoy usando Autocomplete de JQuery pero puede ser con un Select también.

Comment: cual es tu error? o ¿que necesitas?

Comment: No me funciona lo que llevo hasta ahora, me marca que no hay resultados y no sé si exista otra manera de hacerlo o cuál es mi error.

Comment: Y como uso para llamar la funcion updateinput()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomé prestada unas respuestas de **stackOverflow** en inglés que me ayudaron mucho, así que pondré cómo las adapté a mi problema:

Utilicé el atributo *data* y en donde hago mi *select* asigno a una variable cada registro que deseo llenar en el formulario:

**Consulta de sql con la que se llena el select inicial y obtiene los campos en un data**

```
$stmt=sqlsrv_query($dbcon, $sql);
                if($stmt==false){
                    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }

                while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 $clave_ct_necesidad = $row['clave_ct_necesidad'];
                 $clave_ct_nomina = $row['clave_ct_nomina'];
                 $clave_ct_analitico = $row['clave_ct_analitico'];
                 $qna_ini=$row['qna_ini'];
                $qna_fin=$row['qna_fin'];
                    $asignatura=$row['asignatura'];
                    $observaciones=$row['observaciones'];

                    echo "<option data-clave_ct_necesidad='".$row['clave_ct_necesidad']."' data-clave_ct_nomina='".$row['clave_ct_nomina']."' data-clave_ct_analitico='".$row['clave_ct_analitico']."' data-qna_ini='".$row['qna_ini']."' data-qna_fin='".$row['qna_fin']."' data-asignatura='".$row['asignatura']."' data-observaciones='".$row['observaciones']."' value='".$row['plaza']."'> ". $row['plaza']."</option>";


 }
```

Y luego genero una función en Javascript que toma los datos almacenados en cada *data* y los llena en el campo correspondiente:

**Función de Javascript que toma los data y los asigna al campo de texto**

```
function updateinput(e) {
     var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
     document.getElementById('clave_ct_necesidad').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-clave_ct_necesidad');
     document.getElementById('clave_ct_nomina').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-clave_ct_nomina');
     document.getElementById('clave_ct_analitico').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-clave_ct_analitico');
     document.getElementById('qna_ini').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-qna_ini');
     document.getElementById('qna_fin').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-qna_fin');
     do
        cument.getElementById('asignatura').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-asignatura');
     document.getElementById('observaciones').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-observaciones');
    }
```

Y me funcionó perfectamente. Espero sea de utilidad para alguien más.

Answer (score 1):

ya entendi jiji  mira tienes que crear un metodo onchange= "cambio()" cuando hagas un cambio  en tu html se activa ese metodo

```
function cambio(rfc){
            $.ajax({
                url:   'index.php?accion=buscarRfc&rfc='+rfc,
                type:  'post',
            success:  function (data) {
                                     $('#nombres').val(data.empleados_nombres);
                    $('#apellidoPaterno').val(data.empleados_apellido_paterno);
                    $('#apellidoMaterno').val(data.empleados_apellido_materno);
                    $('#calle').val(data.calle);
                    $('#numeroInterior').val(data.numeroInterior);
                    $('#numeroExterior').val(data.numeroExterior);
                    $('#delegacion').val(data.delegacion);
                    $('#codigoPostal').val(data.codigoPostal);
                    $('#idEstado').val(data.estado);
                    $('#estado').val(data.nombre);
```

}
    }

vas a la base y haces tu consulta o lo que vayas hacer y returnas tu resultado con un echo $respuesta o si es un arreglo echo json($respuesta).

luego haces el recorrido con tu data

Comment: Sí sé hacer la consulta, lo que no puedo hacer es que al cambiar el select o usar Autocomplete se llenen los demás campos vacíos.

Comment: ahi te comente dime si es eso lo que quieres

Comment: Lo voy a analizar y probar. Comento si algo hace falta o si tengo más dudas, gracias.

Comment: fernanda siempre has echo o console.log() para ver donde sigue funcionando tu codigo

Comment: Fernanda* Y sí, estoy revisando consola e inspeccionando elementos. Sólo me dice que no hay resultados en el autocomplete y en Select no sé cómo tomar el resto de la información y que se muestre en campos de texto.

Comment: en el network si trae datos tu consulta?

Comment: Las consultas sí sirven, las uso en otros lados de mi proyecto.

Comment: que paso si acabaste?

Comment: Pues utilicé otro método sin Ajax, utilicé Javascript y el atributo data. Publiqué la solución, de hecho.

Comment: Que hace esa (e)
me sale un error Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
en esta linea: var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex];